# caching a value using memcache in yii2

Tags: php, memcached, yii2

I followed the documentation and configured my config/main.php as they stated.

now i try to access the memcache object as the following

```
Yii::$app->cache->Memcache->add('12', '12');
```

and get the value as the following

```
Yii::$app->cache->Memcache->get('12')
```

i don't get anything in the network section in chrome's inspect element feature for a few seconds and then i get this error:

"MemcachePool::add(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok it was a small configuration error, i forgot to set the host as localhost -__-

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @RahilWazir IMO this is an answer to the question - it explains what solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the example from my project.

```
    $key = 'my_key';
    $employees = \Yii::$app->cache->get($key);
    if ($employees === false) {
        $employees = Employee::findBySql('some sql statement')->all();
        \Yii::$app->cache->set($key, $employees, 43200); // time in seconds to store cache
    }
```